# JQuery ajax post data(json) to laravel, then laravel create data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

Excuse me, I want get employ value to ajax post,

then laravel controller get data(json) insert to database,

but jquery.map "bruce" is error, How can I do? , Please Help me thanks!

this is json 
format

```
{"data":{"bruce":"[{"employ":"bruce"},{"employ":"peter"}]","_token":"UiKUMMZRqTgYv5"}}
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="bruce">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="peter">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="abcd">
<input type="button" class="btn ahr-button_2 employ" value="efgh">
<a href="#" class="finish_sumbit">完了</a>
```

Javascript

```
$('.employ').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(".finish_sumbit").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  var data = $('.employ.active').map(function() {
    return {
      'employ': this.value
    }
  }).get();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "business_a",
    async:false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {bruce:data,_token:token},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);

    }
});

});
```

laravel route

```
Route::post('/business_a', 'BusinessController@business_a');
```

laravel controller

```
public function business_a(Request $request)
    {
        $employ = new Employ;
        $b = $employ::create([
                'employ' => $request->bruce,          
        ]);
     }
```

Comment: What's the complete error?

Comment: @AminahNuraini Sorry, HTTP 500 Internal Server Error ,  but  I think it is my  ' $request->bruce ' error,  json format is trouble... but I don't know how to solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first access the input or use the `get()` method on `$request`:

```
public function business_a(Request $request)
{
    $employ = new Employ;
    $b = $employ::create([
            'employ' => $request->get('employ')        
    ]);
 }
```

Comment: thank you, but is  ' [{"employ":"bruce"},{"employ":"peter"}]' ,  I want get employ value, I try $request->get('bruce[employ]') is error .. sorry.. how can I do? thanks